# How to easily check whether an input is in a list/set in C

Tags: c

I am not sure how to easily check whether an input is in a list/set in C.

Is there any built-in function or method to check whether input $\in$ list or set?

For example : inList(input, list) -> output true or false;

Thank you all sincerely.

Edit : list/set what I mentioned above means in real life list/set or mathematically used terms.

Comment: C doesn't have any kind of "list" or "set" data-structure, why should it have such a function?

Comment: To add to above, other languages' notions of 'list' and 'set' usually imply *very* different data structures, operators, operations, and functions.  Colloquially, "list" and "set" might be understood to have similar meanings, but in programming/formal languages, this is not even a little bit true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in function for doing this in C. You have to implement it yourself.

This example code checks whether or not the input character is in the specified array.

```
// booleans are usually represented by ints (1 = true, 0 = false)
int inList(char inp, char* list, int listLen) {
    int there = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listLen - 1; i++) {
    // listLen gets decremented because we don't want an invalid memory access
        if (list[i] == inp) {
            there = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return there;
}
```

You can test this code with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h

int inList(char inp, char* list, int listLen) {
    int there = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listLen; i++) {
        if (list[i] == inp) {
            there = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return there;
}

int main() {
    char list[10] = {"g"};// initialise first element to 'g'
    char inp;
    printf("Please enter a character to check\n >> ");
    scanf("%c", &inp);
    if (inList(inp, list, strlen(list))) {
        printf("\n%c is in the list!\n", inp);
    } else {
        printf("\n%c is not in the list.\n", inp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Mind, this must be changed to check things other than chars w/ strings.

Comment: Note that `char list[10] = {"g"};` does not `// initialise all elements in list to "g"`. It initialised only the first element to `'g'` and the rest to `'\0'`. And I don't get why you pass `10` for the list length, and then the function takes 1 off that. If the list length is (supposed to be) `9` then pass `9`. Better is `strlen(list);` but it is a simple array, not any kind of list structure.

Comment: You're right, that's my bad. I've been paranoid from an invalid memory access in Java I got recently.